# Add Class to clicked li object

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

How to add `class="active"` to a clicked `li` object? 
It isn't currently working when I click the link. Please find below my code.

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
                    <ul id="menu" class="nav">
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Anasayfa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About.aspx">Hakkımızda</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">Hizmetlerimiz <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="WebDesign.aspx">Web Tasarım</a></li>
                                <li><a href="GraphicDesign.aspx">Grafik Tasarım</a></li>
                                <li><a href="MatbaaHizmetleri.aspx">Matbaa Hizmetleri</a></li>
                                <li><a href="PromosyonHizmetleri.aspx">Promosyon Hizmetleri</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AcikHavaReklam.aspx">Açık Hava Reklamcılığı</a></li>
                                <li><a href="StandUygulamaları.aspx">Fuar Stand Uygulamaları</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="References.aspx">Referanslar</a></li>

                        <li><a href="Blog.aspx">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">İletişim</a></li>                           
                    </ul>
                </div>


header.navbar .nav > li.active > a, header.navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover {
            background: transparent;
            color: #2dcc70;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu > li > a').click(function () {
                $('#menu > li > a').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your Jquery is adding/removing the class from the link when the CSS has it applied to the `li`

Comment: Yes but now working.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$('#menu li a').click(function () {
            $('#menu li a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: unfortanetly not working this code. How can I do :(((

Answer (score 0):

Read the code below, hope this Helps!

```js
var selector = '.nav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li.active {
  color: #323643;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code is not working my project. Click the menu page is postback. But menu not active. Why..